# Crystal Reports: how do i export a table to excel data and insert line breaks without getting everything on one horizontal line?

Tags: crystal-reports

i'm new to CR. i have a report basically consisting of 2 tables of data(data comes from several subreports, not crosstab) and whenever i export to excel data it all comes out under 1 line, the entire report.

i've tried adding adding Chr(10)/Chr(13)/Chrw(10)/Chrw(13) at the beginning of each line, together with the data as well as a separated formula but only get an empty cell, instead of a new line.
if i separate the data in different sections, i'd lose the "table" look as i cannot extend lines&boxes over the section length.
i'm out of ideas at this point. anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: get the data into a single data set. For example, use a Command/View/SP with a UNION ALL in the SQL.

Option 2: at least one of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports tools listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched) allows you to automate the process of exporting one report to Excel and append the Excel export of a 2nd report to the same Excel workbook and worksheet.